# How to search an array of hashes for the name of the hash containing a certain key-value pair? (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, hash

I've got something like this:

```
array = [
  hash1 = {"marco"=>"polo", "girth"=>"skinny", "onion"=>true},
  hash2 = {"darco"=>"johnson", "girth"=>"wide", "onion"=>false},
  hash3 = {"flarco"=>"kiwi", "birth"=>"noble", "onion"=>false}
]
```

where one and only one `onion` is `true` at any given time.

I want an expression or function to return the name of the variable (i.e. `hash1`, `hash2`) that holds the hash whose `onion` is currently `true`. How can I do that?

Comment: That is one weird array definition. Why are you defining hash variables inside the array definition? Because you can? That's like an instant fail for "code clarity and maintenance 101".

Comment: Yeah, I guess having the variable declarations inside the array isn't a thing! I've only been at it two weeks ;)

Comment: +1, you taught me something there, I never considered variable assigments inside an array :-)))

Comment: @BorisStitnicky me too :) First time i am seeing..also :))

Answer (score 5):

This is impossible. An object doesn't know about variables which reference it.

Comment: I see. Is there a way to return a certain key from the hash in `array` whose `onion` is `true` (not `onion`'s key, though)?

Comment: @user2493615 If it turned out that this answer does not correctly answer your original question, then I have nothing to say, but if you withdrew acceptance of this answer because you changed your mind about what you wanted to ask, then you should not do that. If you came up with a different question, then ask that as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Similar effect can be achieved by replacing array with hash and making `:hash1`, `:hash2` and `:hash3` keys.

Assuming we've got `hash` variable:

```
hash.keys.select{|key| hash[key]['onion']}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! All the stuff with classes and symbols and single and double @ signs just confuses the dickens out of me.

Comment: ...so the value of a key-value pair can be another hash?

Answer (score 0):

But if you relax the requirements a bit by allowing colons `:` instead of `=` signs:

```
array = [
  hash1: {"marco"=>"polo", "girth"=>"skinny", "onion"=>true},
  hash2: {"darco"=>"johnson", "girth"=>"wide", "onion"=>false},
  hash3: {"flarco"=>"kiwi", "birth"=>"noble", "onion"=>false}
]
```

We could work with that:

```
-> *_, **p { p.find { |_, v| v["onion"] }.first }.( *array )
```

Answer (score -1):

Okay as you asked in the comment section of the post made by *@Jörg W Mittag* - **Is there a way to return a certain key from the hash in array whose onion is true (not onion's key, though)?**. Yes it is possible as I have shown below:

Here I considered one input array,where more than one `Hash` present,which are having `true` value for the key *onion*. Now to handle this situation `enum#find_all` will be needed.

```
array = [
  {"marco"=>"polo", "girth"=>"skinny", "onion"=>true},
 {"darco"=>"johnson", "girth"=>"wide", "onion"=>true},
  {"flarco"=>"kiwi", "birth"=>"noble", "onion"=>false}
]

array.find_all{|i| i["onion"]== true}.map{|i| i.keys[0]}
#>>["marco", "darco"]
```

As per the input array of *OP*, `enum#find` would work.

```
array = [
  {"marco"=>"polo", "girth"=>"skinny", "onion"=>true},
 {"darco"=>"johnson", "girth"=>"wide", "onion"=>false},
  {"flarco"=>"kiwi", "birth"=>"noble", "onion"=>false}
]

array.find{|i| i["onion"] }.keys[0]
# => "marco"
```

Comment: @user2493615 Yes... Enjoy ruby in your way. It will always make you satisfy. And the question you asked in the comment,put it in the description of your question using **EDIT**. Then only my answer would make sense.people might not be able to find your comment.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but per the OP there is only one true onion. Therefore, you could use `array.detect{|h| h["onion"]}` to get the hash.

Comment: @MarkThomas Yes you are right. But I tried to show him a situation,when multiple `true` does exist, and how to handle that. Bur as per you I am editing with `#detect/#find` also.